# WordPress and Ubuntu, www-data and ubuntu for FTP

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, ftp, wordpress

I posted this in stackoverflow but no one can give me an answer.

...

I'm using Amazon EC2. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm also using Apache 2. I have WordPress installed on my server.

I do:

```
chown -R ubuntu /var/www/html
```

so I can edit my files as `ubuntu` via FTP. But the problem is now WordPress cannot edit files, update, or upload any files via WordPress. But if I do:

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/html
```

then it works.

Any way I can make it work for both `ubuntu` and `www-data` at the same time, without always switching it?

Thanks!